# Can't get Extended SNMP output in Perl

Tags: perl, snmp, net-snmp

I have written a Perl script to put back some SNMP values, which works fine. I have now written a script on the remote server and used the extend function in [SNMP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SNMP) to put the value from the script into SNMP.

If I run:

```
snmpget -v2c -c public 10.0.0.10 'NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line."cc_power"'
```

I get the result:

```
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line."cc_power" = STRING: 544
```

But when I try to use my script to get the information back it doesn't get it. Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl     

use strict;
use SNMP;
use RRDs;

my $rrd_db = "/storage/db/rrd/cc_power.rrd";

my $sess;
my $val;
my $error;

$sess = new SNMP::Session(DestHost => "10.0.0.10", Community => "public", Version => 2);
my $power = $sess->get('NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line.\"cc_power\"');

$error=RRDs::error;
die "ERROR while updating RRD: $error\n" if $error;

my $date=time;
print "Data Script has been run - Output: ${date}:${power}\n";
```

but nothing is returned, and I have no idea why... no errors or anything, have I missed something stupid?

Hope someone can help as this is driving me nuts :)

Comment: Use wireshark to check if the SNMP get is send correctly from your script. Check the reply as well and compare it with packets captured when the net-snmp get is successfully used.
You should also enable SNMP debug to see if there are some problems. 
$SNMP::verbose = 1;
$SNMP::debugging = 1;

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the idea, but after i posted, i thought that maybe i should try with the OID, and it worked, so there is something not translating well...

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you used netsnmp snmpget. Well, it hides too many details from you, as it loads MIB documents in background and nicely translate OIDs and SNMP values to all kinds of user friendly formats.

So next time pay attention to what decoration it performs and simulate that in your own code to achieve the same effects.